# How to skip a level in an HTML list?

Tags: html

I have a use case where I'm auto-generating HTML from arbitrary input which might result in a list which skips a level, e.g.:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

  <head>
    <title>Skipping a level in a list</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>Valid HTML
        <ul>
          <li>
            <ul>
              <li>But displays an awkward extra marker</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Invalid HTML
        <ul>
          <ul>
            <li>But no extra marker, looks good</li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

As described in there I can either have awkward looking but valid HTML or better looking but invalid HTML. Obviously I'd rather have good looking and valid HTML.

Is there anything I can do about this? Keep in mind that I also want to support a structure like this:

```
- Lorem
    - Ipsum
  -Dolor
```

Comment: Is there server language generating the HTML like PHP?

Comment: That honestly doesn't make sense to me: why would it be nested two levels deep without an intermediate parent/link?

Comment: This is a simple case of a bad generator. The issue could trivially be handled by not rendering the skipped level, which is a JS job not an HTML concern. You could also handle this through CSS, but you would need to add a class to the marker you want to hide.

Comment: @JohnVandivier, not rendering the skipped level would put `Lorem` at the same level as `Dolor` which would be wrong. Hiding the skipped marked via CSS sounds feasible though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS to skip the second or whatever level.

It's best to use a css class depends on your use case.

**For example:**

```
.item-level-not-visible{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```css
ul ul{ /*skip second level*/
  list-style-type: none; 
}

ul ul ul{
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

  <head>
    <title>Skipping a level in a list</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>Valid HTML
        <ul>
          <li>
            <ul>
              <li>But displays an awkward extra marker</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Invalid HTML
        <ul>
          <ul>
            <li>But no extra marker, looks good</li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Up-voted because CSS is the proper way to do this, but note that classes are preferred to element-based rules. For example, if you add another level deep you will notice the issue returns.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is the valid method you used. You could do something like this, but I am not sure what method of writing would be preferred by other developers:

```
<ul>
    <li><ul>
         <li>List item</li>
     </ul></li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
    <li><ul><li>List item</li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't mean the HTML code being awkward but the output. Please have a look at the rendered result, there is an extra marker there.

Comment: Yes, I saw the extra marker and never knew that could happen. I saw the other answer gave a good explanation of how to fix it. Thanks for your question! I found it as something useful and interesting to know.